# Interval using with arguments.callee breaks "require" behaviour

Tags: node.js, arrow-functions

I'm a rather confused as to why some "requires"

returns an error :

TypeError: require is not a function at Timeout._onTimeout (...........index.js:8:18)

When the following is executed:

```
(()=> {
  console.time("pipeline")
  pipeline().then((result) => {
    console.log("Then: " + result)
    console.log("Work Complete for iteration: " + i + " calling iteration no:", i = i + 1)
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error("error occured with promise resolution: " + error)
  });
  console.timeEnd("pipeline")
})()
```

it runs once then errors (even though I am apparently connected to the db)

but works as expected when changed to this format:

```
(function () {
  console.time("pipeline")
  pipeline().then((result) => {
    console.log("Then: " + result)
    console.log("Work Complete for iteration: " + i + " calling iteration no:", i = i + 1)
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error("error occured with promise resolution: " + error)
  });
  console.timeEnd("pipeline")
})()
```

The error suggests this is relating to the timeout which I would think because it executes once before throwing an error.

Why is this behavior occurring ?  Is this relating to the arguments.callee and if so why?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arguments` refers to parent function scope in case of arrow function. [Arrow functions don't have own `arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Node.js modules are wrapped with [module wrapper function](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper) under the hood:

```
(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
// Module code actually lives in here
});
```

This is what `arguments.callee` refers to inside arrow function. Calling `arguments.callee` results in evaluating current module again with wrong arguments, `require` in particular.

Relying on `arguments.callee` is hacky. A better way to do this is to refer a function explicitly:

```
(function foo() {
  ...
  setTimeout(foo, 1000);
  ...
})()
```

While an arrow will require block scope to not leak `foo` to parent scope:

```
{
  let foo;
  (foo = () => {
    ...
    setTimeout(foo, 1000);
    ...
  })()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) 

I tried the below and noted it "seems" to work the same, however also noted that "this" context did not return the expected either so referencing an arrow function has the same effect/rules as other arrow functions

(conveyer = async () => {
 console.log(this) // returned {}
    setTimeout(conveyer, 1000);
})()

as opposed to your example which returns the global this

(function foo() {
  console.log(this) //returns node global {}
  setTimeout(foo, 1000);
})()

Comment: Linked article explains the difference between arrows and regular function. What expected `this` value in your case? In a situation like this where parent function scope is module `this` doesn't need to be used at all. I specified what arrow IIFE should look like if you need it.